# Provider for type class java.net.URL returned a null value (Arquillian)

Tags: java, jboss, junit, integration-testing, jboss-arquillian

I've been trying to make this test work:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
@RunAsClient
public class AnnotatedEchoServletTestCase {
    @Deployment(testable = false)
    public static WebArchive getTestArchive() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "servlet-test.war").addClass(EchoServlet.class);
    }

    @ArquillianResource
    URL deploymentUrl;

    @Test
    public void shouldBeAbleToInvokeServletInDeployedWebApp() throws Exception {
        String requestUrl = deploymentUrl + EchoServlet.URL_PATTERN.substring(1) + "?" + EchoServlet.MESSAGE_PARAM + "=hello";
        String body = StreamReaderUtil.readAllAndClose(new URL(requestUrl).openStream());
        Assert.assertEquals("Verify that the servlet was deployed and returns expected result", "hello", body);
    }
}
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
Provider for type class java.net.URL returned a null value
```

If I remove the `@ArquillianResource URL` from the code, the test pass without error.

What could be missing if I have this arquillian.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

    <container qualifier="jbossas-managed" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <!-- If you want to use an existing JBoss AS installation, change the value of this property to that path -->
            <!-- If you've already set the JBOSS_HOME environment variable, you can remove this configuration block -->
            <property name="jbossHome">target/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final</property>
            <property name="outputToConsole">true</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>

</arquillian>
```

Comment: To confirm, are you using AS 7.1.1? And are you using the AS 7.1.1 Arquillian container adapter in your test classpath, and not a different version?

Comment: My bad, I just forgot to set 'arquillian-jbossas-managed' as the active maven profile in Eclipse... it works now.

Comment: Ah, ok. This issue occurs only when the metadata is not available for the deployment, or if the `@ArquillianResource` annotation is defined for an absent servlet. If you need to know how this works, look further into the [`URLResourceProvider`](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-core/blob/master/container/test-impl-base/src/main/java/org/jboss/arquillian/container/test/impl/enricher/resource/URLResourceProvider.java#L59) class.